# Bit mask operation not clear- what code is doing

Tags: bit-manipulation

Any idea what this func returns?
I'm not sure why it's shifted by 1 on the second line

Thanks

```
bool findWhat(U32 bitmask)
{
   U32 bitmaskOdd = bitmask & 0x55555555;
   U32 bitmaskEven = (bitmask & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1;
   U32 bitmaskXor = bitmaskOdd ^ bitmaskEven;
    
   if (bitmaskXor & bitmaskEven)
   {
     return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take as example a bitmask with all four possible variants of adjacent bits in odd and even positions:

```
    8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1    Position (counted 1-based)
    0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1    bitmask
```

Resulting *bitmaskOdd*:

```
    0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1    bits in odd positions are kept
```

Resulting *bitmaskEven* without shift:

```
    0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0    bits in even positions are kept
```

Resulting *bitmaskEven* with shift:

```
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1    bits in even positions are kept but shifted
```

*bitmaskXor* as bitwise `XOR` of *bitmaskEven* and *bitmaskOdd*:

```
    0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Bitwise `AND` of *bitmaskXor* and *bitmaskEven*:

```
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

As the `AND` is not zero, the function returns `true`.
This indicates that there is an adjacent pair of bits in even and odd position where the even bit is set and the odd bit is not set.

In other words: The function returns `true`, if there is at least one `10` pair of adjacent bits, where the right-hand bit is in an odd position.